# .textContent not replacing text

Tags: javascript

I'm new to use javascript but having been running into an issue regarding the .textContent function in a script editing an existing webpage.

Instead of replacing the text content, it simply appends the string to the end. Looking at the HTML, the original text is in a span while the text I intended as a replacement ends up outside the span but still in the div. How would I go about replacing the span text entirely?

It ends up looking like this

```
<div class="errorMessage" data-reactid="180"><span>Original Text</span>Intended Replacement text.</div>
```

Comment: Can you show some sample code? Because it sounds like you're using a reference to the wrong DOM object.

Comment: Can you show how you’re using it? The description sounds like it’s outside the span, inside the same element, and not inside anything else, which would be strange.

Comment: Oh, it’s React. React is going to do its own thing.

Comment: Your `span` has no id or class, but your `div` does have a class. You're probably using a reference to the div, not the span.

Comment: @kshetline Yes, I actually used document.getElementsByClassName("errorMessage") to find the reference. How would I go about referencing the span instead of the div?

Comment: Use `document.querySelector('#errorMessage span')`

Comment: @ZacharyIsaacson Welcome to SO. Please do post your code which doesn't work so we can help you in better manner. Also, check my answer which should fix your problem. Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

Give your `<span>` an id like `<span id="error-id">`, then use `document.getElementById('error-id')` to get a reference to the span. Or you could just move the class you already have to the span instead of the div, and continue to use `document.getElementsByClassName("errorMessage")`.

Update: Randy Casburn's suggestion is good too.

Comment: No - the span does NOT need an id attribute. the OP simply needs to use `document.querySelector('#errorMessage span')`

Comment: @RandyCasburn, yes, your way is good too, perhaps even better than what I first thought of.

Comment: I have an affliction that makes me have spasms when we start putting id attributes on every element on the page for simple things like this. Thanks for indulging me.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Your answer, `document.querySelector('#errorMessage span')` will get any span children of an element with ID `errorMessage`, right? I think you meant to write `document.querySelector('.errorMessage span')`, and maybe `document.querySelector('.errorMessage > span')` would be better still. Cheers!

Comment: @LimitedAtonement - 1. yes, it is a class not an ID (after 5 months, who knows what untracked changes have been made to the OP) 2. No, `> span` is NOT more appropriate given the OP's HTML structure that I commented on when there was an ID on the div. - thanks for the update. But since the OP never had the courtesy to respond to anyone's help - this won't be helpful anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var ele = document.querySelector('.errorMessage span').textContent = 'Intended Replacement text';

/* InnerHTML can also be used but it is slower than the textContent as it parses HTML */
// ele.innerHTML  = 'Intended Replacement text';
```

```html
<div class="errorMessage" data-reactid="180"><span>Original Text</span></div>
```

Comment: using `.textContent` instead of `.innerHTML` wherever possible is probably a better practice.

Comment: Yes it is. Difference could be trivial in this case. :)

Comment: After this snippet runs, `ele` = `Intended Replacement text`, right? That's probably not intended.